# Can't login with KDM and SSSD but the login works fine from the console

Tags: kde, ldap, pam, openldap

I have LDAP authentication set up with SSSD and I can login fine through console and ssh. However when I try to login through KDM it just says authentication failure... More specifically:

```
Jan  9 10:29:11 adams20420 sssd[be[default]]: Failed to set LDAP SASL nocanon option to true. If your system is configured to use SASL, LDAP operations might fail.
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM pam_parse: expecting return value; [...sufficeint]
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_console.so): /lib64/security/pam_console.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_console.so
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: pam_ldap: ldap_starttls_s: Operations error
Jan  9 10:29:24 adams20420 kdm: :1[4560]: pam_unix(kde:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:1 ruser= rhost=  user=igierl1
```

Here is the pam.d/kdm

```
auth       required    pam_env.so
auth       substack    system-auth
account    required    pam_nologin.so
account    include     system-auth
password   include     system-auth
session    required    pam_loginuid.so
session    optional    pam_console.so
session    optional    pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    required    pam_namespace.so
session    include     system-auth
```

system-auth:

```
auth            sufficient      pam_ldap.so
auth            required        pam_env.so
auth            required        pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth            optional        pam_permit.so

account         sufficient      pam_ldap.so
account         required        pam_unix.so
account         optional        pam_permit.so

password        sufficeint      pam_ldap.so
password        required        pam_cracklib.so difok=2 minlen=8 dcredit=2 ocredit=2 retry=3
password        required        pam_unix.so try_first_pass use_authtok nullok sha512 shadow
password        optional        pam_permit.so

session         required        pam_limits.so
session         required        pam_env.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
session         optional        pam_ldap.so
session         optional        pam_permit.so
```

Additional info:
Distribution - Gentoo

Local accounts work fine, and logging in through ldap via ssh and/or console works. The only problem is logging in through KDM. That's when the error shows up.

ldap.conf

```
timelimit 120
bind_timelimit 120
idle_timelimit 3600

TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts
URI ldaps://hucsc2.hofstra.edu/
BASE dc=<sub>,dc=<domain>,dc=edu

# Just assume that there are no supplemental groups for these named users
nss_initgroups_ignoreusers root,ldap,named,avahi,haldaemon,dbus,radvd,tomcat,radiusd,news,mailman,nscd,gdm,polkituse$

ssl start_tls
TLS_CHECKPEER no
TLS_CRLCHECK none
TLS_REQCERT never
pam_password md5
```

nsswitch.conf

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf:
# $Header: /var/cvsroot/gentoo/src/patchsets/glibc/extra/etc/nsswitch.conf,v 1.1 2006/09/29 23:52:23 vapier Exp $

passwd:      files sss
shadow:      files sss
group:       files sss

hosts:       files dns
networks:    files dns

services:    files sss
protocols:   files
rpc:         files
ethers:      files
netmasks:    files
netgroup:    files
bootparams:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return]files
publickey:   nisplus
automount:   files ldap
aliases:     files nisplus
```

Comment: Take a look at this and post the additional config files - http://www.gentoo-wiki.info/OpenLDAP

Comment: Added the extra configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

It was answered on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/566150/cant-login-with-kdm-and-sssd-but-works-fine-from-console/566240?noredirect=1#566240

In short, i should use pam_sss.so instead of pam_ldap.so